# Autogenerated Gridview with All Cells in Edit Mode by Default

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

So I've got a gridview bound to a SQL datasource stored procedure. The stored procedure returns a pivot table, where a number of columns are unknown until run time. I therefore need to autogenerate the columns.

The gridview is intended to allow Excel-like data updates. So the goal is to have the grid load as textboxes. I know if I were to declare the columns on my aspx page, I could create template columns and handle their visibility that way.

So I believe I need a way to programmatically set all the columns to template fields (without knowing the column names), or I need to discover the method by which I can just "flip the switch" and just make everything editable.

Thanks in advance!

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceExcelGridTest">
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceExcelGridTest" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:WebAppsConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="spJobForecastingGetEmployeesByDepartmentAndProject_v1" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" UpdateCommand="spJobForecastingUpdateHours" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="DepartmentNumber" Type="String" DefaultValue="13211" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ProjectNumber" Type="String" DefaultValue="13211" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="startDate" Type="DateTime" DefaultValue="2/21/2014" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="DepartmentNumber" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ProjectNumber" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Alias" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="WorkWeek" Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="WorkHours" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:
***UPDATED CODE***

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceExcelGridTest">
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceExcelGridTest" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:WebAppsConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="spJobForecastingGetEmployeesByDepartmentAndProject_v1" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" UpdateCommand="spJobForecastingUpdateHours" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:Textbox ID="DepartmentNumber" DefaultValue="13211" text='<%# Eval("DepartmentNumber") %>'></asp:TextBox> 
    <asp:Textbox ID="ProjectNumber" Type="String" DefaultValue="13211" Text='<%# Eval("ProjectNumber") %>'></asp:TextBox> 
    <asp:Textbox ID="startDate" Type="DateTime" DefaultValue="2/21/2014" Text='<%# Eval("startDate") %>'></asp:TextBox> 
</SelectParameters>
<UpdateParameters>
    <asp:Textbox ID="DepartmentNumber" Type="String" text='<%# Eval("DepartmentNumber") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Textbox ID="ProjectNumber" Type="String" text='<%# Eval("ProjectNumber") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Textbox ID="Alias" Type="String" text='<%# Eval("Alias") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Textbox ID="WorkWeek" Type="DateTime" text='<%# Eval("WorkWeek") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Textbox ID="WorkHours" Type="Int32" text='<%# Eval("WorkHours") %>'></asp:TextBox>
</UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: You will need to edit the above to match your CSS inputs, and also your database entries.  But this will get it done.

Comment: James - this solution appears to use hard coded columns (not an option), and does not use a gridview (not a deal-breaker, but I loose the gridview's built in operations, which meanse I'll have to create those myself). Also, I'm not sure where this would go. I guess this would be called on page_load?

Comment: wow, my mistake, let me convert it over to aspx format.  Right now it is in vbhtml format.

Comment: better yet, take a look at this: (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSASPNETGridView-5b16ce70)  they give the whole solution to your problem using gridview.  The only issue is that it is in c#.  If you can provide any code that you have created so far to perform this action, it would make things a lot easier for me to help you implement it.

Comment: Just found the vb code for the same example.  Here you go (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/VBASPNETGridView-19039173), enjoy.

Comment: James - the linked solutions are demos/tutorials for a basic gridview, which uses hard coded columns and therefore can hard code EditItemTemplates for each column. As my columns are not known until run time, these solutions will not work for me. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Karl, they aren't hard coded anywhere.  That sample pulls the data from a database, populates the gridview, and then allows for users to edit those values that were populated.  Check this site out (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37207/Editable-Gridview-with-Textbox-CheckBox-Radio-Butt).  Both articles are the same in that they are giving the edit function to the gridview.  Maybe I'm confused as to what you are doing, but without any coding, it is hard to see everything that is going on with this portion of your project.

Comment: Basically, you would use the above method, call a refresh of some sort on the pivot table when the datagrid is updated.  A simple post would cause this refresh.  Or you could call a function in javascript to perform this refresh on the pivot table.

Comment: James - I appreciate your persistence, but the example clearly shows columns declared, with templatefields containing edititemtemplates. These fields are bound to columns in the datasource by name, and as such will not work for me. You can't do this with columns with names that are unknown. I will edit my question so you can see the the basic declaration of my gridview, and hopefully that will illustrate what my words have failed to do thus far.

Comment: Let me see if I understand this correctly.  You are populating the database tables and their fields at runtime?  Honestly, that in itself is very confusing, as your tables in the database should be contants.  such as, you should know that in database X, table Y, the following fields are available: yId, yForm, yNew, etc.  These are all consistant.  when accessing the data in the table, you access it by the constant fields.  So, a request could be From Y of X, what is the data for yForm, yNew which has a yId of 4.

Comment: Keep in mind, when making a database, there should always be a main table that has a Id of entries, and then links to other tables in the database are made using common titles.  For example, yForm of Y table is equal to yForm of Z table.  Thus linking the entries of each individual database together.

Comment: Just updated the code, take a look at it.  the areas like `'<%# Eval("WorkHours") %>'` are where you place the table field title from the database.  In fact, your Default Value for each item can be removed, as the string will pull the first entry and display that anyways.  For this, if I were you, I'd have 3 tables all together, the first 2 tables are entries into the forth table.  You can populate dropdown menus from the first three table to help populate data into the 3rd table.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47964/discussion-between-karl-and-james)